# Side Chain in Ardour

Tags: sound, compression, ardour

Can someone familiar with Ardour 2.8 please make a video / youtube guide showing precisely how to use SC3 Side Chain Compression?  I've read every guide online currently and side chain is simply not working, very frustrating.  http://ardour.org/node/1013 seems to be the main one people go by, however when I have the sends coming into the bus there is simply no effect from SC3.  Thank you for your time.

Here is another relevant thread: http://ardour.org/node/3882

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice guy over on the Ardour forums was kind enough to explain what I was doing wrong.

> Create a new 3-channel bus
>   Add an SC3 to that bus, set Chain balance on the SC3 to 1 and the others to taste
>   Add a send from the kick track to input 1 of the bus
>   Add a send from the bass track to input 2 (and optionally 3) of the bus
>   Make sure the bass track is not connected to any output
>   Hit play
>   Profit!
>
> Clear all the automation you currently have on the SC track and set all the automation items to Manual.
>   Set the SC3 compressor to
>   Attack=2
>   Release=130
>   Threshold=-16
>   Ratio=4
>   Knee=3
>   MakeupGain=5
>   You can play around with Thresh, Ratio and Gain to get the perfect balance. If you decrease Thresh you have to compensate by increasing Gain

From what I've seen, these settings will give you a starting point to start fiddling around with to get the kind of side chaining you'll be looking for.  Kudos to the man named "peder".  [Ardour Post](http://ardour.org/node/3882)

Answer (score 0):

- 1 stereo track for the synth to duck
- 1 stereo track for the ducking signal
- 3-channel bus for the SC3 plugin
- Output 1 & 2 (left & right) of the synth track go to input 1 & 2 of the SC3 bus
- Output 1 or 2 (left or right) goes to input 3 of the SC3 bus

And this is the important (and counterintuitive) bit

- Output 1 & **3** of the SC3 bus go to the system/playback 1 & 2

(Tested in [qtractor](http://qtractor.sourceforge.net/))